# Como restringir un login en una aplicacion web con Spring?

Tags: java, html, base-de-datos, spring

Estoy realizando un proyecto de aplicación web hecho con Spring en el que uso HTML, Java y Oracle SQL (para la base de datos). Mi duda es que uno de mis códigos HTML es para un login en la aplicación, pero me gustaría poder enlazarlo con la base de datos, de forma que sólo se permita el acceso a la web si el usuario y contraseña introducidos están en la tabla USER de la base de datos. Este es mi código HTML real:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Iniciosesion</title>
</head>
<body>

    <center>
        <img src="Imagenes%20de%20inicio/icono.png">
        <h2>Usuario</h2>
        <input type ="text" name = "username">
        <h2>Contraseña</h2>
        <input type ="text" name = "password">
        <a href="index.html"><input type="button" value="Ir"></a>
        <form action="Coger_datos" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Ir">
        </form>

        <a href="usuario/add.html"><input type="button" value="Crear cuenta"></a>
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

También he encontrado una plantilla Java para acceder a una base de datos Oracle, pero no sé cómo relacionarla con mi código HTML para que todo se conecte:

```js
package es.uma.ingsoftware.goldendumbbell.Controller;

import java.sql.*;


public class Coger_datos {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {

        System.out.println("\nEstableciendo conexión...");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("zzzzz", "xxxxxx", "yyyyy");
        System.out.println("Conexión establecida\n");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        String consulta = "SELECT CONTRASEÑA FROM USUARIO where usuario.nombre = 'javimp2003'";
        System.out.println("Se va a ejecutar la consulta: " + consulta);
        System.out.println("\nIniciando transacción...");
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(consulta);

        System.out.println("Resultado de la consulta:");
        while (rset.next()) { 
            int ncol = rset.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= ncol; i++) { // for: Itera sobre las columnas de la fila
                System.out.print(rset.getString(i));
                if (i < ncol)
                    System.out.print(" | ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Finalizando transacción...");
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
        System.out.println("\nConexión finalizada");
    }
}
```

Comment: Investiga sobre Spring Security. Lo que quieres es sumamente comun y varias formas de lograrlo, asi que para este punto, la mayoria de las respuestas que te podriamos dar son relativamente subjetivas o son mas adecuadas para un tutorial (Algo para lo que StackOverflow no fue pensado en realidad).